# Component calls Reselect only at the first time it renders

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reselect

[image]

I'm building Multiple Select component for user to select the seasons on the post. So use can choose Spring and Fall. Here I'm using `reselect` to track selected objects.

My problem is that my reselect doesn't trigger one it renders at the first time. This question looks pretty long but it has many console.log() lines for clarification. So please bear with me! :)

('main.js') Here is my modal Component. Data for `this.state.items` is `seasons = [{id: '100',  value: 'All',}, { id: '101', value: 'Spring',}, { ... }]`

```
return (
  <SelectorModal
    isSelectorVisible={this.state.isSelectorVisible}
    multiple={this.state.multiple}
    items={this.state.items}
    hideSelector={this._hideSelector}
    selectAction={this._selectAction}
    seasonSelectAction={this._seasonSelectAction}
  />
```

('main.js') As you can see I pass `_seasonSelectAction` to handle selecting items. (It adds/removes an object to/from the array of `this.state.selectedSeasonIds`). `selectedSeasonIds: []` is defined in the state. Let's look at the function.

```
  _seasonSelectAction = (id) => {
    let newSelectedSeasonIds = [...this.state.selectedSeasonIds, id];
    this.setState({selectedSeasonIds : newSelectedSeasonIds});
    console.log(this.state.selectedSeasonIds); <- FOR DEBUGGING
    console.log(newSelectedSeasonIds); <- For DEBUGGING
  }
```

I confirmed that it prints ids of selected Item. Probably providing code of SelectorModal.js is irrelevant to this question. So let's move on... :)

('main.js') Here is where I called `createSelector`

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    seasons: SelectedSeasonsSelector(state)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(...);
```

(selected_seasons.js) Finally, here is the reselect file

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

// creates select function to pick off the pieces of states
const seasonsSelector = state => state.seasons
const selectedSeasonsSelector = state => state.selectedSeasonIds

const getSeasons = (seasons, selectedSeasonIds) => {
  const selectedSeasons = _.filter(
    seasons,
    season => _.contains(selectedSeasonIds, season.id)
  );
  console.log('----------------------');
  console.log('getSeasons');
  console.log(selectedSeasons);    <<- You can see this output below
  console.log('seaons');
  console.log(seasons);
  console.log('----------------------');
  return selectedSeasons;
}

export default createSelector(
  seasonsSelector,
  selectedSeasonsSelector,
  getSeasons
);
```

The output for system console is below

```
----------------------
getSeasons
Array []
seaons
undefined
----------------------
```

Thank you for reading this whole question and please let me know if you have any question on this problem.

**UPDATE** As Vlad recommended, I put SelectedSeasonsSelector inside of _renderSeasons but it prints empty result like above every time I select something. I think it can't get state.seasons, state.

```
  _renderSeasons = () => {
      console.log(this.state.seasons) // This prints as expected. But this becomes undefined 
                                      //when I pass this.state in to the SelectedSeasonsSelector
      selectedSeasons = SelectedSeasonsSelector(this.state)
      console.log('how work');
      console.log(selectedSeasons);
      let seasonList = selectedSeasons.map((season) => {
          return ' '+season;
      })
      return seasonList
  }
```

`state.seasons` and `state.selectedSeasonsIds` are getting **undefined**

Comment: This is reselect example video that I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCQ0ZSr-a2o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are assuming that `this.setState` will change redux store, but it won't.

In a `_seasonSelectAction` method you are calling `this.setState` that stores selected ids in **container's local state**.

However selectors are expect ids will be be stored in **global redux store**.

So you have to pass selected id's to redux store, instead of storing them in a local state. And this parts are looks missing:

1. `dispatch` action
2. use `reducer` to store this info into `redux` store.
3. add `mapDispatchToProps` handler to your `connect`

I'm guessing here, but it looks like confusing terms:component local **state** is not  the same as redux store **state**. First one is local to your component and can be accessed through `this.state` attributive. Second is global data related to all of your application, stored in redux store and could be accessed by `getState` redux method.

I so  you probably have to decide, whether to stay with redux stack or create pure react component. If pure react is your choice, than you dint have to use selectors, otherwise you have to dispatch action and more likely remove `this.state`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer with deep explanation. But I didn't assume that this.setState will change redux store. I know how it works but in this case I'm using `reselect`. The beauty of `reselect` is that it reduces unnecessary calculation when we send data from state to props. From my point of view, dispatching actions are inefficient in this case.

Comment: I highly want to avoid to send an actions to redux in this case.

Comment: Oh hold on wait

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting you right. This is the video tutorial I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCQ0ZSr-a2o

Comment: you can avoid sending actions, its for sure, but can you than clarify your expectations from selector: what should it return?

Comment: It should return `seasons` array which contains selected season. ( i.e, [ 'Fall', 'Spring'])

Comment: I think I got your point. I think I haven't sent data to redux yet. I guess reselect doesn't do everything for me.

Comment: Yes - reselect is just advanced getters. However - if you want to skip redux loop here (for any reason), you can use them to read your local state as well. Just call it like  `selector(this.state)` somewhere inside  you component.

Comment: your `this.state` have `items` but selectors expect `seasons` attribute to be defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157710/discussion-between-vlad-and-john-baek).

Comment: When I press Button, it performs `this.setState({items: seasons})`. Probably there is something bad happening on my reselect. I just edited my question